# Fitting text into BufferedImage

Tags: java, swing, java-2d

I wrote this program to find a way I could draw a `String` centered onto a `BufferedImage`  of any size (in this case, the size of the `BufferedImage` is the same as the `JPanel` its in) and location. When I resize the `JFrame`, the text flickers as it repositions itself in the `BufferedImage` and I don't know why.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class test extends JPanel
{
    double scale = 0;
    String draw = "1";

test()
{
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    paintText(g2, 0, 0);
}

public void paintText(Graphics2D g, int x, int y)
{   
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D big = (Graphics2D) bi.getGraphics();
    FontMetrics fm = big.getFontMetrics(); 

    scale = bi.getHeight()/(fm.getHeight());
    double xt = -(((scale*bi.getWidth())-bi.getWidth())/2);
    double yt = -(((scale*bi.getHeight())-bi.getHeight())/2);
    big.translate(xt, yt); 
    big.scale(scale, scale);
    big.drawString(draw, (bi.getWidth()/2)-(fm.stringWidth(draw)/2), (bi.getHeight()/2)+(fm.getHeight()/4)+1);
    g.drawImage(bi, x, y, this);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
    frame.add(new test());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: you can enable double buffering on your `JPanel` by calling `setDoubleBuffered(true);`

Comment: @ug_ Which should be enabled by default

Comment: The issues surrounds your translation and positioning calculations, which are not generating an accurate enough result, which is causing the resulting image to be "bounced" about when the frame is resized. Try removing the translation and rendering the text at position 0x0 to see what I mean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The major problem is your attempt to translate and the center the text within the `BufferedImage`, the calculations are causing a certain amount of drift as the size of the window is changed, meaning that they don't produce an accurate position.

After much stuffing around, I basically threw out your `BufferedImage` and `setScale` approach and simple derived a new font based on the `scale` property.

Now, you could still generate a `BufferedImage`, but I would use the resulting `FontMetrics` to determine the actual size of the image and simply render the image at the center position of the frame...but that's me

[image: ScaledFont]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

class Test101 extends JPanel {

    double scale = 0;
    String draw = "1";

    Test101() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        paintText(g2, 0, 0);

        int x = getWidth() / 2;
        int y = getHeight() / 2;
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2.drawLine(x, 0, x, getHeight());
        g2.drawLine(0, y, getWidth(), y);
    }

    public void paintText(Graphics2D g, int x, int y) {
        
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        
        FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
        System.out.println(fm.getAscent());
        scale = getHeight() / (fm.getHeight());
        
        Font font = g.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(scale, scale));
        g2d.setFont(font);
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        fm = g.getFontMetrics(font);
        int xPos = (getWidth() - fm.stringWidth(draw)) / 2;
        int yPos = ((getHeight() - fm.getHeight()) / 2) + fm.getAscent();
        g2d.drawString(draw, xPos, yPos);
        g2d.dispose();
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
                frame.add(new Test101());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't know you could derive a font using an `AffineTransform` like that.

Comment: Yeah, it's a neat little feature ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because your GUI runs in the same thread as the Image is located, try to do the JFrame in an own Thread.

Comment: Swing is not thread safe, the only code that any UI code should run on is the Event Dispatching Thread, which `paintComponent` will be called from

Comment: How should I do that? Should I use invokeLater() in the main method or something?.

Comment: @JayKay Because of the way the painting works, `paintComponent` will ALWAYS be called within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  Also, until you call `pack` or `setVisible`, the Frame doesn't have a connection to a native peer, therefore it's impossible to be painted.  The act of setting the frame visible places the request on the EDT, so it becomes a little irrelevant.  The underlying issue is with your position calculations, which seems to be making the output "jump", it has nothing to do with the underlying paint process